# Proving an infinite sum can take on arbitrarily small values

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, summation

> Show that we can pick $x>0$ sufficiently small that \begin{equation}\frac{x}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{x^2}{3\cdot 4}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\cdots<k\end{equation} for any $k\in(0,1).$

My idea: The sum we want is as follows:

\begin{equation}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(n+1)(n+1)}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(n+1)^2}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n^2}\end{equation}

But if we choose $0<x<1$ then we have that this sum is at most $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, by the fact that the sum of the reciprocals of the squares is this value. But I can't see how to obtain the required result. Is there a way to find a closed form?

Comment: For $0 < x < 1$ is the sum at most $x \pi^2/6$ ...

Comment: @MartinR in fact at most $\frac12 x$

Comment: This is true for any power series with non-negative coefficients, no constant term, and radius of convergence $\geq 1.$ Technically, you don't need the non-negative condition, I suppose...

Comment: It is pretty clearly false that we can pick $x>0$ sufficiently small that $\frac{x}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{x^2}{3\cdot 4}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\cdots<k$ for any $k\in(0,1).$ What's true is that for any $k\in(0,1)$ we can pick $x>0$ sufficiently small that $\frac{x}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{x^2}{3\cdot 4}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\cdots<k$.

Comment: Using the beta-function, one can show that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{(k+1)(k+2)}=\frac{1}{x^2}\Big(\ln(1-x)+x-x\ln(1-x)-x^2/2\Big)\to\frac{1}{2}\,\text{at}\,x\to1$$

Answer (score 5):

You could do $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^2} = x\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{n^2}\right)<x\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=x\frac{\pi^2}{6}\leq k$$ for $x<\frac{6k}{\pi^2}$.

Comment: +1 as that works, but slightly tighter $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n+1)(n+2)} = x\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right)\le x\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right)=\frac{x}{2}$ for $0 \le x\le 1$, and so less than $k$ for $0 \le x \le \min(1,2k)$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach:

Your series is clearly less than

$$x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots = \frac{x}{1-x} < 2x ~: x < \frac{1}{2}.$$

Therefore, you can choose **any** $x$ less than $~\displaystyle \frac{k}{2}.$

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(n+1)(n+2)} \implies S{x^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$ Differentiate twice
$$\left( S{x^2}\right)''=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n=\frac x {1-x }$$ Integrate twice
$$S=\frac{(2-x) x+2 (1-x) \log (1-x)}{2 x^2}$$

Then, for any $0\leq k \leq \frac 12$, there is an $x$